# R package DESCRIPTION not showing on?

Tags: r, roxygen2

Building an R package in RStudio roxygen2. Have these setting in Roxygen configure (below). However, after I build, I'm unable to see the nice documentation when trying:

```
> ?PackageName
```

It just gives:

```
No documentation for ‘PackageName’ in specified packages and libraries:
```

you could try ‘??PackageName’

The DESCRIPTION file is just a standard description file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create in the /R directory of the package a specific file containing the description of the package as well as `@docType package` and `@name` roxygen tags :

```
#' MyPackageTitle
#' 
#' Description of MyPackage
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name MyPackageName
NULL
```

NULL is necessary at the end, as no other object is defined here.

This file usually has the name of the package :  MyPackageName.R

see http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages

Comment: Nice thanks @waldi! I just had to add a @title for it to work (it gave an error saying missing name and title)

Comment: @SOUser It worked for me too.

Comment: @SOUser, I updated my answer to clarify what I meant by description of the package (AFAIK you won't need `@title` with this header)