# @title Missing name at line 1

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2, rd

I was getting this error when running `devtools::document` but had no idea how to troubleshoot. The file that popped up on my installed package when I entered `?MyPackage-package` did not match the text in `MyPackage-package.R` at all. I initially suspected it might have been from adding the awesome citation functionality from `RDpack`, but this was not the culprit. How did I go about ultimately fixing the problem?

Comment: The first thing I'd check is that the title lines of each of your functions are properly formatted.  This is not obviously connected to Rdpack -- have you tried removing RdMacros and redocumenting? Could title lines contain characters that Rdpack is misinterpreting?

Comment: Are you sure this message is from 'R CMD check'? It doesn't write NAMESPACE. It looks like a message from devtools. If you haven't resolved this yet, a link to your package would enable concrete help.

Comment: @Georgi Boshnakov, thanks for this. I'll do a bit more troubleshooting/cleanup and then if still stuck I'll link to the package.

Comment: @GeorgiBoshnakov, looks like I tracked down the issue at last. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error resulted from incorrect formatting in my `PackageName-package.R` file.

I had heavily edited the file created by `usethis::use_package_doc()`, and added all of my roxygen comments **Below** the default content added by `usethis`. After looking at the [documentation for `merTools`](https://github.com/jknowles/merTools/blob/master/R/merTools-package.r), I saw that it was *ok* to have the [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62271320/8400969) I understand to be important for `roxygen2` to make the .Rd files **after** and **not before** all the other roxygen comments.

After moving the stuff created by `usethis::use_package_doc()` (and not just the `NULL` line; that was already at the end) to the bottom of the .R file, everything seemed to render fine and this error disappeared.

Comment: Late response, I missed your answer at the time. Adding this comment to add more context for future visitors. ```

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was published prematurely, I didn't realise that pressing 'Enter' publishes the comment. I missed your answer at the time. I use `usethis` package and it is great for helping with arcane stuff but I find the file created by `usethis::use_package_doc()` (which I  just checked) not very helpful without referring to the roxygen2 documentation. I personally start off with a file from some other package, as you did above.